# Dynamically casting an object to the correct subclass

Tags: c#, casting

Assuming I have the interface `IApple`, and the class `Apple` that implements it. Additionally, I have several classes that extend `Apple` (`SpartanApple`, `GreenApple`, etc..)

Now, I have the following function that will handle adding the apple to my database:

```
public void CreateApple(IApple apple) 
{
    ...

    db.Apples.Add(apple);    // This will take an object of type Apple, or ANY of its sub-types
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem is `db.Apples.Add(apple);` will give the following compile-time error

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'IApple' to 'Apple'
```

So I need to cast `apple` to the appropriate type before passing it to `Add()`. I can get do it by using if statements and casting `apple` to the appropriate type based on certain properties, but I don't want to have to add a new case every time I add a new subclass in the future.

I feel like I'm missing something trivial here. Is there a more elegant way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: General tip - if you need to downcast, your design is probably wrong.

Comment: Did you try casting it to `Apple`? `db.Apples.Add((Apple)apple);` EF should figure out actual type properly inside `Add` method.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek You're absolutely right. I tried it and it did just that. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just cast it to `Apple`. EF will figure out actual type properly inside `Add` method:

```
db.Apples.Add((Apple)apple);
```

**Update**

As @AntP mentioned, you can avoid casting by changing method signature to accept `Apple` instead of `IApple`:

```
public void CreateApple(Apple apple) 
{
    ...

    db.Apples.Add(apple);
```

Comment: Question - what's the point in having `CreateApple` accept an `IApple` if you're just going to cast it to `Apple` unless your goal is to encourage exceptions? Why not just have `CreateApple(Apple apple)` instead? At least then you can do your casting in the caller and avoid having a misleading interface definition.

Comment: @AntP You should ask Sadiq.

Comment: No, I should ask you because you're posting this as an answer when it clearly doesn't address the underlying problem in the question.

Comment: @AntP I've updated my answer, but I don't think it was totally wrong before. If I'd like to address every underlying problem I would probably never answer a single question on SO...

Comment: I'm not really sure where you're coming from with that - if all your answers do is turn code that won't compile into broken code that will compile, maybe not answering would be for the best.

Answer (score 3):

If the only purpose of `CreateApple` is to save it to the repository that only accept `Apple`s, then just change the signature:

```
public void CreateApple(Apple apple) 
{
    ...

    db.Apples.Add(apple);    // This will take an object of type Apple, or ANY of its sub-types
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

If the reason for using an interface in `CreateApple` is to not have a dependency on the implementation, then that model is broken if you *internally* need to case to an `Apple`.

Another option is to create a *new* `Apple` and just map from `IApple`:

```
public void CreateApple(IApple apple) 
{
    Apple newApple = new Apple()
    {
        Color = apple.Color,
        Variety = apple.Variety,
        ...
    }

    db.Apples.Add(newApple);   
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

That way you're *still* loosely-coupled and could use a *different* implementation of `IApple` without having to change your repository code.